# Increasing number of socket connections

Tags: performance, benchmarking, vert.x

I have an app that uses websocket. So far after rigorous trying, I am able to make 65000 connections but my resources are still largely free. How can I increase the number of connections.

The backend code is written in Java Vertx
Verticle

```
public class HttpVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    static int connectionCount = 0;
    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
        server.websocketHandler(serverWebSocket -> {
            System.out.println("Connection established: " + (++connectionCount));
            serverWebSocket.closeHandler(handler -> {
                System.out.println("Connection Closed");
            });
        });
        server.listen(8888);
    }
}
```

Main App:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("server started @ 8080");
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(new HttpVerticle());
    }
}
```

My system configurations:

```
Dell latitude
16Gb ram
intel core i7
```

Memory Information while 65000 connections are established:

```
16313976 total
6009728 used
10283896 free
```

What is the maximum connections that I can make with this configuration and what are the ways to increase this number of connections? I see that large memory is still free, so how can I increase this connection?

And my system settings

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.core.rmem_max = 33554432
net.core.wmem_max = 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 16384 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 16384 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 786432 1048576 26777216
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 360000
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 2500
vm.min_free_kbytes = 65536
vm.swappiness = 0
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535
```

/etc/security/limits.conf

```
myusername hard nofile 1000000
root soft nofile 1000000
root hard nofile 1000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with ephemeral ports, usually you'll run out of sockets one you reach almost 64k connections. In order to overcome this you might start the same server in different ports and distribute the connections across each listening port to be close to 50000 each.

That was the trick used by [C10M](http://goroutines.com/10m) while creating a benchmark for Go. Also the article does explains the limitation and how they solved it. Though it was written with Go in mind it can be applyed to any language and for sure to [Vert.x](http://vertx.io).

Comment: Thank you so much. But I made an approach where I started an nginx server in port 8000. And created 3 different servers in 8001,8002,8003. The idea was to distribute the connections to these three servers using nginx load balancer. But when it tried this approach, the nginx load balancer itself was taking only 65k connections. Any idea how can I approach such problem?

Comment: I think this is the same issue, you have 3 servers but ngnix is a single server so it will exhaust the ephemeral ports once it reaches ~64k connections, you will still need to either launch several ngnix servers or drop it and connect to the vert.x servers directly

Comment: how does these kind of problems get solved normally? I guess applications using websocket are not just restricted to 65k connections?